# Heatmap default value zero color

Tags: python, heatmap

I collect different sets of data. Based on the min and max value of this set of data, I would like to construct my colorscale. Actually I would like to have no colouration. I am using the imshow function instead of the seaborn library. How I could achieve my goal.

```
        plt.imshow(dekaX, vmin=min_, cmap='YlGnBu', interpolation='nearest')
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
plt.title("2-D Heat Map X-Side "+ "Timestamp "+str(df_events.iloc[event_id]['timestamp'])+" Relative Event "+str(event_id)+" Absolute Event " + str(df.iloc[event_id]['id']))
plt.colorbar()
plt.savefig('C:\\Users\\demet\\Desktop\\Internship\\SideX\\SideX'+str(event_id)+'.png', format='png', dpi=300)
plt.close("all")
plt.imshow(dekaY, vmin=None ,cmap='YlGnBu', interpolation='nearest')
plt.title("2-D Heat Map Y-Side "+ "Timestamp "+str(df_events.iloc[event_id]['timestamp'])+" Relative Event "+str(event_id)+" Absolute Event " + str(df.iloc[event_id]['id']))
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
plt.colorbar()
plt.savefig('C:\\Users\\demet\\Desktop\\Internship\\SideY\\SideY'+str(event_id)+'.png', format='png', dpi=300)
plt.close("all")
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: What is a color scale with **no** *colouration*? Greyscale? Your [mre] should include example data.

Comment: @wwii Let me give you an example. Certain cells on the heatmap, are not activated, so I would like that they are not part of the colour map. So their colour, is white. So I want to use a different colour scale but once I get a specific value my heatmap is white, for this particular cell

Comment: Are dekaX and Y integers between 0and 255? Again, you should include a minimal example of the data maybe arrays of shape (25,25) or smaller.